# 0 at end of PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

This is taken directly from this W3Schools tutorial, but I modified the php file to use wordpress hooks and the js file to take in two variables, so that it can be used multiple times in a single page: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp.

I have the following gethint.php file:

```
<?php
add_action("wp_ajax_GetHint", "GetHintFunction");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_GetHint", "GetHintFunction");

// embed the javascript file that makes the AJAX request
//wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'ajaxtest.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', plugins_url( '/js/showHint.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );

// declare the URL to the file that handles the AJAX request (wp-admin/admin-ajax.php)
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

function GetHintFunction(){
    // Array with names
    $a[] = "Anna";
    $a[] = "Brittany";
    $a[] = "Cinderella";
    ...
    $a[] = "Wenche";
    $a[] = "Vicky";

    // get the q parameter from URL
    $q = $_REQUEST["q"];

    $hint = "";

    // lookup all hints from array if $q is different from ""
    if ($q !== "") {
        $q = strtolower($q);
        $len=strlen($q);
        foreach($a as $name) {
            if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
                if ($hint === "") {
                    $hint = $name;
                } else {
                    $hint .= ", $name";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values
    echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
}
```

And the following showHint.js file:

```
function showHint(str, str2) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById(str2).innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById(str2).innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", MyAjax.ajaxurl + "?action=GetHint&q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

And here is the html page itself:

```
<p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
<form> 
First name: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value, 'txtHint1')">
</form>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint1"></span></p>

<p><b>Type another name in the input field below:</b></p>
<form> 
Last name: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value, 'txtHint2')">
</form>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint2"></span></p>
```

The problem is that my output has a zero at the end of the response. Here is how it looks:
[browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzuf4.jpg)

I used chrome's developers tool and under XHR, I can see that the PHP response itself contains that zero at the end of the response. Even if I remove the second text box and the second variable from the js function, the issue continues, so the issue seems to be with the php file itself. Any thoughts?

Comment: tested the php locally, no "0" are you sure thats the whole php file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a Wordpress issue. They respond with `die(0)`.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116759/why-does-wordpress-add-0-zero-to-an-ajax-response

Comment: You are correct. I add `die();` at the end of the function before the `}` and now the zero no longer appears. Thank You :)